# How does Spring and Hibernate interpret @Entity and other annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am confused as to how Spring and Hibernate interact through the annotation configuration.

If for example, I have the @Entity or any other '@___' annotation, how does Hibernate know to interpret this differently from Spring or any other annotations that are shared between Spring and Hibernate.

From my understanding, at least for the @Entity annotation, Spring will interpret this as a Java bean, while Hibernate understands this to mean that it will be creating a table for the database.

If then, what does @Id become interpreted for Spring? I know @Id indicates to Hibernate that the variable should be a primary key for the database?

A thorough explanation of the annotation configuration for Spring would be helpful as a precursor to your explanation of how these annotations work.

Thank you.

Comment: *From my understanding, at least for the @Entity annotation, Spring will interpret this as a Java bean,* Nope, how did you came up with that?

Comment: *what does @Id become interpreted for Spring?* nothing, just ignored.

Comment: A tutorial I was reading informed me of that... So then, the annotations or java based configuration, is inherent for Java Spring and with this Spring provides a framework that Hibernate is able to use for its own ORM?

Comment: Spring works on top of JPA, and Hibernate is standard JPA provided that comes with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Both frameworks are reading annotations that they are interested in. Its as simple as that.

Comment: These annotations are provided by the Spring framework?

Comment: You are asking me or telling me?

Comment: Also, how do you know what needs to be scanned? I was reviewing the LocalSessionFactoryBean and saw that you have to include the Model class to be scanned. Is this because SessionFactory is respective to Hibernate and therefore Hibernate needs to know where to look for the @Entity annotation?

Comment: `@Entity` `@Id` and all persistent stuff is a part of JPA not Spring.

Comment: You may have multiple persistance units ("databases") that does not reflect eachother, so you have a way of "grouping" entitities in them,

Comment: Okay so then Entity and Id are a part of JPA, that Spring is able to interpret because it is built on top of the JPA. the '@__' is Spring, but the Entity and Id are a part of JPA which Spring is able to utilize.